# Lemma related to the counting of numbers in list

Tags: coq

I want to solve a lemma which relate two lists after removing a number from the list with the help of following functions. Here is code

```
  Theorem remove_decr_count: forall (l : list nat),
  leb (count 0 (remove_one 0 s)) (count 0 s) = true.
 Used functions are

  Fixpoint remove_one (v:nat) (l:list nat) : list nat:=
   match l with
   | [] => []
   | h :: t => if beq_nat v h then t else h :: remove_one v t
   end.

 Fixpoint leb (n m:nat) : bool :=
  match n, m with
  | O, _ => true
 | S _, O => false
 | S n', S m' => leb n' m'
 end.

Fixpoint count (v:nat) (l:list nat) : nat :=
 match l with
 | [] => 0
 | h :: t => (if beq_nat h v then 1 else 0) + (count v t)
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to proceed is by induction on the list `l` (warning: you used `s` in the theorem's definition, though), and then by case, on whether the head of the list is 0 or not. Rewrites are used to guide the proof.

Using the SSReflect tactics language, the proof could proceed like this (I replaced `beq_nat` by `==`, and added the `leb1` lemma, which is also proved by induction, here on `n`).

```
From Coq Require Import Init.Prelude Unicode.Utf8.
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.

Fixpoint remove_one (v:nat) (l:list nat) : list nat:=
   match l with
   | nil => nil
   | cons h t => if v == h then t else cons h (remove_one v t)
   end.

Fixpoint count (v:nat) (l:list nat) : nat :=
 match l with
 | nil => 0
 | cons h t => (if h == v then 1 else 0) + (count v t)
end.

Fixpoint leb (n m:nat) : bool :=
  match n, m with
  | O, _ => true
  | S _, O => false
  | S n', S m' => leb n' m'
end.

Lemma leb1 (n : nat) : leb n (S n).
Proof. by elim: n. Qed.

Theorem remove_decr_count: forall (l : list nat),
  leb (count 0 (remove_one 0 l)) (count 0 l).
Proof.
elim=> [|h t IH] //=.
- have [] := boolP (h == 0) => eqh0.
  by rewrite eq_sym eqh0 leb1.
- by rewrite eq_sym ifN //= ifN.
Qed.
```